# EF Core : Many to many relation ship with Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a .NET Core project with EF Core (Code First). I'm building an API to learn this framework.

To sum up, the application will enable users to paste their code and share it with other users.
So I have 2 main entity :

- User
- List item

CodePage

```
 public sealed class User : Entity<Guid>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Le nom d'utilisateur de l'utilisateur
        /// </summary>
        public string Username { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Le hash du mot de passe de l'utilisateur
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Le salt du mot de passe de l'utilisateur
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Liste de pages de code dont l'utilisateur est proprietaire
        /// </summary>
        public ICollection<CodePage> OwnedCodePages { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Association User/Page autorisées
        /// </summary>
        public ICollection<UserCodePage> UserCodePages { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

```
public sealed class CodePage : Entity<Guid>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Titre optionnel de la page de code
        /// </summary>
        public string Title { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indication du langage de la page de code
        /// </summary>
        public string Language { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contenu de la page de code
        /// </summary>
        public string Content { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Date de création
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Date de modification
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag indiquant si il s'agit d'une page de code privée
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPrivate { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Propriétaire de la page de code (Anonyme si null)
        /// </summary>
        public User Owner { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Association User/Page autorisées
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<UserCodePage> UserCodePages { get; set; }
...
}
```

What I want is a many-to-many relationship between an User and a CodePage. 
So I followed the docs (https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration). And I have this :

```
public class UserCodePage : BaseEntity
    {

        public Guid AuthorizedUserId { get; private set; }
        public User AuthorizedUser { get; set; }
        public Guid CodePageId { get; private set; }
        public CodePage CodePage { get; set; }

        public UserCodePage()
        {
        }

        public UserCodePage(Guid userId, User user, Guid codePageId, CodePage codePage)
        {
            AuthorizedUserId = userId;
            AuthorizedUser = user;
            CodePageId = codePageId;
            CodePage = codePage;
        }
    }
```

And the entity configuration :

```
internal class UserCodePage : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Identity.Entities.UserCodePage>
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Identity.Entities.UserCodePage> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(o => new { o.AuthorizedUserId, o.CodePageId });

            builder
                .HasOne(o => o.AuthorizedUser)
                .WithMany(o => o.UserCodePages)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.AuthorizedUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);



            builder
                .HasOne(o => o.CodePage)
                .WithMany(o => o.UserCodePages)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.CodePageId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        }
```

I added the `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` because i couldn't `Update Database` without it.

Here is the problem :
I want the `UserCodePage` deleted if the `User` or the `CodePage` linked to it is deleted.
I tried to use the `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` but `Update-Database` fail...

I hope you understood my problem !

Comment: Does it says why it fails when you use Update-Database? I see you have a third relation in your `CodePage` called `UserCodePage`. If it this other depends on it, you cannot delete it

Comment: I fails because the foreign key. The other relation is a One To Many on User to CodePage. (A CodePage has a Owner, an User has multiple owned code page)

Comment: I meant the exact error? if you can provided

Comment: I haven’t my computer on me me but that was something like :  FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Comment: That means you have to configure the other association as `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.

Comment: The other ? The ICollection<CodePage>?

Comment: You have `WithMany(o => o.UserCodePages)` twice. One of the should be `WithMany(o => o.OwnedCodePages)` and only one of them needs to have `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.